# No display on boot after changing hard disk. Motherboard fried?

Tags: boot, graphics-card, display, motherboard, hardware-failure

I just put a new SSD in my computer, replacing an old one. Something I've done plenty of times before but this time when I powered-up the PC I get no display.
When I press the power button all the fans spin and the hard disks power up, but the monitor just says 'DVI no signal'. I also don't think it is actually running through the boot process as I can simply press the power button to switch it off again (normally, if it boots, I'd have to hold it for 5 seconds).

I have an Nvidia card, no display on that (either thru HDMI or DVI) and also onboard graphics, nothing there either. I disconnected the new SSD, no help. I disconnected all drives, nothing. I took out the nvidia card and ran only with onboard - still no display. Finally I took out the RAM and cleaned out as much dust from the case as possible, that didn't help either.

Now I'm kind of out of options. Any ideas what could be wrong in there? I'm somewhat worried that I broke the motherboard while I was changing the drives over. Is that the most likely problem? Otherwise, what else could be causing the issue?

Comment: Broken motherboard is possible, but I would be surprised unless you *really* gave it a knock. Do you definitely have integrated graphics? (I mean, these days its unusual not to but still)

Comment: Yep, definitely has integrated graphics (I've used it in the past with no dedicated gfx card). I also didn't think it'd be possible to break the mobo while changing a ahrd disk but i'm struggling to think what else could cause the symptoms I describe.

Comment: Hmm as am I, if no one else has any other comments I'll do some research for, it might be useful to have the motherboard details and I'll look into it tomorrow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was the screen that was faulty.
I'm still somewhat suspicious as I find it very odd that the screen died at the exact moment that I changed hardware inside the computer. The probability of that happening for no reason must be relatively low.

Anyway, new screen and problem is gone. No mobo issues.